# Next / Previous Posts on Tumblr within Tags

Tags: tumblr

Is there a way in Tumblr to have Next / Previous links only go to posts that share the same tag as the post you are on?

For example, if a post was tagged "Image" the next previous links would only point to other posts that were also tagged "Image".

From my understanding of the [documentation](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#navigation), it is not possible - there are no tag related controls for permalink navigation - but wondering if anyone has come up with any ways to do this.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this, Jeff?

Comment: No, there is no functionality as far as I know that allows this.

Answer (score 0):

To view all of the posts on your tumblelog with a specific tag (let's use #image as an example), you can just type in http://urlofyourtumblelog.tumblr.com/tagged/image and all of the posts you've tagged with #image are shown. Your regular previous and next page links will navigate through tag pages just like they would on any other page.

To give an example, this would be tag page 2 of #dog:

http://urlofyourtumblelog.tumblr.com/tagged/dog/page/2

Comment: You are correct for tag *pages* but I'm referring to *post* link navigation e.g. you are on post page and there are next and previous links for the next post.